# duplicate pages issue on installed script website yii framework

Tags: yii, yii2, duplicates, slug

i want to specify that i have almost no experience with php and yii framework

I am trying to setup a classified ads website with yii ,but after i did some seo audit i realised that almost all of my category pages have duplicates like this :

example.com/category?slug=cars      -this url is a duplicate that i don't want
example.com/category/cars           -this is the url that i want to have

This is my urlManager code :

```
'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'enableStrictParsing' => false,
        'rules' => [
            'search' => 'site/search',
            'contact' => 'site/contact',
            '<controller:conversation>/<action:delete>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:conversation>/<action:reply>/<conversation_uid:[a-z0-9_\-]+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:account>/<action:invoices>/<page:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:account>/<action:conversations>/<page:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:listing>/<action:index|update|package|preview>/<slug:[a-z0-9_\-]+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            'page/<slug:[a-z0-9_\-]+>' => 'pages/index',
            '<controller:category>/<action:location|map-view|get-map-location>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            [
                'pattern' => 'category/<slug:[a-z0-9_\-]+>/<page:\d+>',
                'route' => 'category/index',
            ],
            [
                'pattern' => 'category/<slug:[a-z0-9_\-]+>',
                'route' => 'category/index',
            ],
            [
                'pattern' => 'category/map-view/<slug:[a-z0-9_\-]+>/<page:\d+>',
                'route' => 'category/map-view',
            ],
            [
                'pattern' => 'category/map-view/<slug:[a-z0-9_\-]+>',
                'route' => 'category/map-view',
            ],
            [
                'pattern' => 'store/<slug:[a-z0-9_\-]+>/<page:\d+>',
                'route' => 'store/index',
            ],
            [
                'pattern' => 'store/<slug:[a-z0-9_\-]+>',
                'route' => 'store/index',
            ],
            '<url:.+/>' => 'site/redirect'
        ],
    ],
```

If you need any further detailes or specific code ask me and i will try to provide !
Thanks

Comment: The link on the left works because is the default link to your action. The one on the right is probably configured in your URL rules, I guess that you only want the `example.com/category/cars` to work and not the original version? I am not sure how you would do that.

Comment: Hi can you please provide your code? Currently we can only guess what is wrong. Also please read this guide https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: My bad sorry  and thanks for the head up ! Which code would  you need ? all web.php code , urlmanager or something else ? i will post it  as soon as i get home from work ! Thanks again for your reply

Comment: give `urlManager` to see how you set you url routing. If it cannot be repaird, you'll have to make url redirects in your action

Comment: @DamianDziaduch , urlManager code is now up ! hope that you find something wrong in it because i am going crazy :))

Comment: @vvpanchev hi ,if you want to take a look i added urlManager code